# Should duplicate flags auto-mark helpful?

Tags: bug, flags

As far as I'm aware there are certain flags that are marked as helpful by the system when the action suggested by the flag is taken. Such as when a post is flagged for too broad, and the question is later put on hold for being to broad (although that may be a review based process).

However, I've noticed in my recent flagging history that I flagged a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051527/where-is-the-keyboard-specified-the-system-in-method) as duplicate of an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144859/scanner-in-new-scannersystem-in). Yet the old question was instead marked as a duplicate of the new one and the flag remains "pending".

I'm not arguing on the point of who should be a duplicate of who, but shouldn't the dupe flag on my part be either cleared as helpful or as disputed since the action it suggested was taken, but simply "backwards"?

Comment: The script that marks flags helpful automatically is probably triggered on actions on the post you flagged. No idea how much work it would be to trigger off of other posts being closed as a dupe of the one you flagged instead.

Comment: Good point, would it be fair to assume when a post becomes a destination from a dupe that an action is triggered

Comment: Did Jon Skeet ask the second question? Because the fact list says that when he asks a dupe, the original is closed as dupe. [Soruce](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9277/257207)

Comment: No, if you look at the links to the questions you can see who asked what and who marked what

Answer (score 5):

By flagging the newer question as a duplicate, you pushed that question into the close votes review queue. The fact that the duplicate was applied the other way around doesn't mean that the newer question shouldn't be also closed (maybe for another reason or another duplicate).

Your flag will be either marked as helpful if the question gets closed or it will be marked as disputed when it stays open as soon as the review task is completed. This task may be completed in different ways:

- 5 users that have 3k+ reputation vote to close on the question => ***helpful***,
- 5 users that have 3k+ reputation review that task as to leave it open => ***disputed*** or
- the existing close flags and close votes expire before a consensus can be reached => ***disputed***.

Your flag will probably expire in <strike>6 to 8 weeks</strike> [14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250496).

Comment: Flags expire in 14 days, and as far as I know, they're not exactly considered disputed when they do, either: they don't add to the tally and they can be reraised.

Comment: While I understand the system for reviews on the flagged question, this question focuses on flags being auto marked based on an action on another post, but not the flagged post

Comment: @NathanTuggy Found the 14 day reference, but as what are they marked? They don't just go away, do they?

Comment: @ArtjomB.: They pretty much do. They don't affect your internal flag weight (I strongly suspect), don't contribute toward flag-banning, aren't counted toward any visible display (except total flags raised), and can be re-raised. So for most practical purposes they're basically just deleted.